# Jmeter - use a property value once per Plan

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am storing the needed values (earlier extracted from REST response) inside properties by the following way (beanshell):
[Storing vms_lst_ values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l582q.png)

Later, I need to iterate the values of all properties starting with vms_lst_ , RANDOMLY choose one, and make an API call using the chosen value.
How can i use each value only ONCE per plan?
The key here is randomly picking the value and not iterating them sequentially.
I am using more than one thread, and multiple loops. each value can be used ONLY ONCE per test plan.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the property after it was used like:

```
props.remove("vms_lst_whatever");
```

`props` is basically normal [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) so you can call any method you see in the JavaDoc

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) rather than Beanshell as:

- Groovy is more "modern" language and supports all Java language features
- Groovy has a lot of [enhancements](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of Java SDK
- Groovy has much better [performance comparing to Beanshell and other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks, but thats only part of the solution. I need to randomly choose one property out of all vms_lst_* and only then remove it. Something like 'pop' method for removing from list in Python. Is there something similar that is suitable for my need? If yes, then i would probably need to convert those properties to list (array)?

Comment: Exceptionally I provide you a solution, however SO is not a code-writing sersvice: `def vms_lst_ = props.entrySet().findAll { entry -> entry.value.startsWith('vms_lst_')}.collect()
def randomEntry = vms_lst_.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0,vms_lst_.size()))
props.remove(randomEntry.key)
log.info(randomEntry.value)`.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me with slight modifications: import org.apache.commons.lang.math.RandomUtils


def AAA = props.entrySet().findAll { entry -> entry.getKey().toString().contains('vms_lst_')}.collect() 
def random = new Random();
def randomEntry = random.nextInt(AAA.size())

log.info("@@@ REMOVED " + AAA[randomEntry].getKey())
props.remove(AAA[randomEntry].key)